# Facebook login & Titanium : hash key

Tags: android, facebook, hash, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to implement a Facebook connect in my app, with the appcelerator Facebook module ... but I've got some problems with the hash step.

In the Appcelerator console, I'm running the command : `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.2.v20170120081654/dev_keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

And a hash key appears. I put this one in my Facebook App's parameters, but when I'm clicking on the button "Login with Facebook", a message appears : "Invalid key hash. The key hash XXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes.

The point I don't understand is that I don't know where it's finding this XXXXXXXX hash : it doesn't correspond with any value I put in Facebook or in my files.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the dev_keystore is located in ../sdk version/**android**/dev_keystore ... I've used same command with the correct path and works ok